# how to make multiple api call at the same time?

Tags: php, api, url, coinmarketcap

CoinMarketCap Api offer a lot of data by making calls to different links. Every time you make a call it cost 1 credit and of course, if that call return 5,000 coins then it cost 25 credits. So, I can't make call to different link every minute. How can I make a call to at least 4 links such as:

1. https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/trending/latest
2. [https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/trending/gainers-losers](https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/trending/latest)
3. [https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=5000](https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/trending/latest)
4. [https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/info](https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/trending/latest)

and here is the code that CoinMarketCap offer and it works (tested):

```
   $url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest';
   $parameters = [
     'start' => '1',
     'limit' => '5000',
     'convert' => 'USD'
    ];

     $headers = [
    'Accepts: application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: *********-****-****-****-***********'
     ];
     $qs = http_build_query($parameters); // query string encode the parameters
     $request = "{$url}?{$qs}"; // create the request URL


      $curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource 
       //Set cURL options
       curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
      ));

      $response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
      print_r(json_decode($response)); // print json decoded response
      curl_close($curl); // Close request
```

Comment: multi_curl ?  an example [here](https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/)

Comment: Question: I have to use a KEY...every time I make the call...it charges me 1 credit...if I do curl_multi..will it make different calls? or no matter how many end-points I have it will count as 1 credit? or as # of urls per credit?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the curl_multi_init to handle the multiple curl request asynchronously. [you can read here more about multi curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: how can you modify my code to make it work with multi_curl? I am implementing this code: https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/ and still not working =/

Comment: Question: I have to use a KEY...every time I make the call...it charges me 1 credit...if I do curl_multi..will it make different calls? or no matter how many end-points I have it will count as 1 credit? or as # of urls per credit?